# Defining default values for Boolean arguments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, coding-style, functions

Is it usually recommended to define default values for Boolean arguments?

I mean, is it usually recommended to define a function like this

```
someFunction(a, b, x) {
   // a and b are strings, x is true or false
   ...
}
```

or like this?

```
someFunction(a, b, x = false) {
   // a and b are strings, x is true or false
   ...
}
```

In either case, the function can be called without `x`:

```
someFunction(a, b);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Default values - are they good or evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63908/default-values-are-they-good-or-evil)

Comment: @DocBrown I would say my question is slightly different. It's not about a general case of using default values, but about specifying a default `false` value which is - in JavaScript - essentially optional. I do understand that this is very subjective and a matter of coding style, but I haven't found any mention of this case in style guides in which I looked for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript is somewhat different in this regard as it's very loose about it type and method definitions, and it fills in a lot of the gaps for you.

In this particular case, the two are completely equivalent. But this relies on two key notions:

- Javascript doesn't care about missing method parameters to begin with.
- You are setting the default value of the method parameter to the default value of a boolean (i.e. `false`)

If you change either of these notions, it ceases to be equivalent. Below are two examples of this.

However, before we get to the examples, I want to address your question:

> Is it usually **recommended** to define default values for Boolean arguments?

Recommendations are not always done for technical benefit. It could be of a documentative nature.

For example, while the behavior between your two methods is exactly the same, if I were to start using your code, I would infer that `someFunction(a, b, x)` isn't intended to be called with missing parameters, whereas if I see `someFunction(a, b, x = false)`, I can infer that whoever designed this method specifically **expected** that the third parameter might be omitted.

That doesn't change how the code works, but it does change my understanding of the author's intention when designing this method, so it changes how I develop this code further (e.g. not going round and "fixing" all method calls which seem to have "forgotten" the third parameter).

So is it recommended? Well, that depends.

- As a blanket rule? No, that's silly.
- As a way to indicate that omitting this parameter in this method is expected and not a problem? Yes, that's a great way of communicating that to future readers of your code.
- As a way to actually change how the code behaves? Well, yes, but in your particular example, it doesn't quite matter since any uninitialized boolean will already be `false` anyway.

---

**Example 1**

For example, if you want `x` to be `true` by default. Compare these examples:

```
someFunctionWithoutOptionalValue(a, b, x)      { console.log(x == true); }  
someFunctionWithOptionalFalse(a, b, x = false) { console.log(x == true); }
someFunctionWithOptionalTrue(a, b, x = true)   { console.log(x == true); }
```

And we run this script:

```
someFunctionWithoutOptionalValue(a,b);
someFunctionWithOptionalFalse(a,b);
someFunctionWithOptionalTrue(a,b);
```

You will notice the following output:

```
false
false
true
```

When you define your optional value to be *different* from what the default value already is, then this makes a change to how the code behaves.

---

**Example 2**

While this may be less relevant for you now, if we move to another language which is much stricter with its typing but also has optional parameter values (I pick C# here), then the two examples you gave also are no longer equivalent.

```
public void SomeFunction(int a, int b, bool x) {}
public void SomeFunctionWithOptional(int a, int b, bool x = false) { }
```

I'm allowed to do either of these:

```
SomeFunctionWithOptional(1, 2, true);  // x will be true
SomeFunctionWithOptional(1, 2);        // x will be false
```

And I'm allowed to call:

```
SomeFunction(1,2,true);                // x will be true
```

But I am not allowed to omit a non-optional parameter:

```
SomeFunction(1,2);                     // COMPILER ERROR
```

In strongly typed languages, you **must** mention that a method parameter is optional before you are allowed to actually leave it empty when calling the method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a fantastically awesome answer.

Comment: Your first example actually prints `undefined false true`, not `false false true`. It doesn't matter if you have `if (x)` because `undefined` is falsy, but if you're doing something else with `x`, the two function definitions are _not_ equivalent.

Comment: @Jasmijn Good catch. Changed the printed value to `x == true` to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

As for whether it is "usually recommended", the answer is no.  However, there are cases where a default value for a boolean makes sense.

Something to consider: I suggest that the default value usually be **false**.  That way the behavior is "as expected in JS": a missing parameter is falsy.

This may mean that the name of the parameter gets switched.  For example, if the method deletes all nodes, with an option for recursive, and the "most typical" behavior should be recursive is true, I suggest

`deleteNodes(parent, dontRecur)`

instead of

`deleteNodes(parent, recur=true)`

YMMV.  If the reversed name is just too corny or unexpected, don't follow this advice.

Comment: I started to think this way in every language. If you have a boolean it's easier to assume it's false by default, so it becomes falsy when omitted in such languages. Unfortunately, this rule will break for public APIs where the default behavior needs to be changed. You should not change the variable name when the default value changes. If it's private I often rather refactor, though.